# unable to enter view the data entered in the textbox when template customization is applied to a textbox in windows phone

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I was trying to customize the textbox control in the windows phone application. I have done with the customization of the textbox using controltemplate and when i run the application I can't view the data that is being entered on to the textbox. the following is my xaml code:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="True" Name="txtemailVal" Height="46"
        BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="170,203,0,338" Width="258">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="LightSeaGreen"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="5">
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
    <TextBox.InputScope>
        <InputScope>
            <InputScopeName NameValue="EmailUserName"/>
        </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

could anyone help me to reslove this issue? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a control to actually "host" your text, by default this is a `ScrollViewer`, so something like this should do the trick:

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="True" Name="txtemailVal" Height="46" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,203,0,338" Width="258">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="LightSeaGreen" 
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    CornerRadius="5">
                <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="ContentElement" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
    <TextBox.InputScope>
        <InputScope>
            <InputScopeName NameValue="EmailUserName"/>
        </InputScope>
    </TextBox.InputScope>
</TextBox>
```

Notice that the `ScrollViewer` is called `ContentElement`. This is a "named part" and is documented in the [MSDN article on `TextBox` stlyes and templates for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as being the element where the text is displayed. Other controls have named parts, too, so if you're customizing several controls, I suggest you take a look at the other articles too.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have added the scrollviewer. However, it makes no difference. I have forgot to add this point in my question like....I can not see the cursor atleast to enter the input values in the textbox. though if I enter correct credentials i could enter in to application successfully...I mean I could not view the text or cursor placed in the textbox.

Comment: my bad, I gave you the WPF name instead of the Silvelight name, I corrected the code. I also tried to retag your question, since WP7 is Silverlight, not WPF, but it'll go faster if you do it yourself ;)